# Starting a Junior Security Consultsnt job soon

Tags: penetration-test

I’ve just graduated university in information security and applied for various jobs. I really wanted to get a role as a junior pen testers but was told it was difficult without any experiance. Obviously I have done a full 3 year course but to me it felt fairly basic. Anyhow, I’ve been given the job offer as junior security consultan (pentesting). The interview basically consisted of a 2 hour technical interview. I felt in the interview I was only able to answer 50% of the questions asked. I feel so under qualified for the role I’ve been offered and now just worried I’ll fail probabtion. They also hinted that they’d expect me to complete the OSCP exam in the first few months.

If someone could just explain in general terms what’s usually expected from a junior pentester that may put my mind at ease a little.

Comment: Every company is different. For every job, and even I still do this, ask them what their expectations are of you for the first 90 days. Get them to define it in hard metrics then make sure you deliver. Then schedule a review meeting after 90 days to review.